# Count values of dict-like object in multiple files

Tags: grep

I have three txt files that have this format:

File 1:

```
{
"username1":10,
"username2":11,
"username3":100,
}
```

File 2:

```
{
"username1":4,
"username5":15,
"username6":25,
}
```

File 3:

```
{
"username1":6,
"username2":19,
"username6":25,
}
```

I would like a json file (a `dict` object) containing the sum of the values of each username. That is, I would like:

```
{
"username1":20,
"username2":30,
"username3":100,
"username5":15,
"username6":50,
}
```

Each username could appear in each file; each username will occur a maximum of 1 time in each file. The string `usernamei` is an alphanumeric string of length >=1. It could be `Stacy60` or `evergreen` or `0`, etc.

That is, if `username1` appears in file1, it only appears once in file1; it could appear again in file2 or file3 or both, but only once in each file.

Since these are txt files, I'm having a hard time reading them in as dict objects in Python, and thought there might be a nice `grep` or `cat` solution to this. I'm not sure how to get it right, though. I've tried:

```
grep -o '[[:alnum:]]":"[0-9]+" ./file_*.txt | cut -d '"' f1 | sort | uniq -c > all_usernames.json
```

It didn't work, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Does the last entry in each object actually have a comma at the end? If so, neither input nor output is valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, each entry does have a comma at the end.

Comment: Python has a good json package that would make short work of this.

Comment: Except each input file is not in json format; they're txt files. Does that matter?

Comment: @StatsSorceress There can be various nice solutions through command line, but are you sure you wouldn't like a python solution ? that format is exactly python's format for dict literals and those files can be easily slurped in by a very short and simple python script

Comment: I'm trying a Python solution right now, but it's being ridiculously slow - hours so far! I was hoping there might be a simpler way through bash.

Comment: @StatsSorceress, how large are those files? One way to go about this would be as follows: Slurp those files into python dicts, use each of those dicts to prime a `collections.Counter` instance and all the Counter instances together

Comment: Hi @iruvar, thanks! Can you write up a solution like that? If it's faster than what I'm currently doing, I'll accept it. I'm using a loop to read in the files, and looping through the lines to count stuff.

Comment: @StatsSorceress, here's a start `from collections import Counter; import json; Counter(json.loads('{"username1":10, "username2":11, "username3":100}')) + Counter(json.loads('{"username1":4, "username5":15, "username6":25}'))`

Comment: Hi @iruvar, these are long files. What I posted was an example, but there are tens of thousands of username:count pairs.

Comment: @StatsSorceress, long files wouldn't necessarily be a problem. Look into `json.load` for loading json straight from a file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91829/discussion-between-statssorceress-and-iruvar).